# Show errors in my gdb log report

Tags: gdb

Here is a sample session directly from gdb console

```
Starting program: 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Breakpoint 1, 0x00000000025654f0 in ~F()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000000025654f0 in ~F()
    at hello.cpp:123
(gdb) c
Continuing.
foo.cpp:122:12: runtime error: member call on null pointer of type 'Object'
```

Here is my `.gdbinit` file

```
set pagination off
set language c++
set print pretty on
set logging file gdb.txt
set logging on

break ~F()
info breakpoints
r
bt
c
set logging off
quit
```

and the gdb.txt produced looks something like this:

```
Breakpoint 1 at 0x25654f0
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address            What
1       breakpoint     keep y   0x00000000025654f0 <~F()>
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Breakpoint 1, 0x00000000025654f0 in ~F()
#0  0x00000000025654f0 in ~F()
....

Breakpoint 1, 0x00000000025654f0 in ~F()
```

I don't see `foo.cpp:122:12: runtime error: member call on null pointer of type 'Object'` coming out in the log. How do I get that into my log?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That message come from your program, not from gdb.

One way to make it work is to have your program and gdb write to the same log.  The only trick here is to make sure they are both writing in "append" mode.  There is a "set logging" subcommand for this, and for your program, you can run like:

```
(gdb) run >> log
```